# Alamofire post request error Extra argument 'method' in call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm using xcode 9.2 I want to make a post request however I'm getting  this error "Extra argument 'method' in call". I know it's talking about the post method but i dont know how to fix it, can anyone help?

```
Alamofire.request(URL_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding, headers: header).responseString {
            (response) in
            if response.results.error == nil {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.resultd.error as Any)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your attributes probably aren't valid (if the types don't match Xcode will tell you the error with the closest matching function)

try changing `JSONEncoding` to `JSONEncoding.default` and that your `body` matches `[String:Any]`

```
Alamofire.request(String, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: [String:Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
```

something along these lines (I don't know about the header attribute I usually have this at `nil`)

Comment: I changed JSONEncoding to JSONEncoding.default and that worked!  Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, these are little errors that are usually quick to solve

Answer (score 0):

It probably is because your body variable isn't [String: Any]